# GlassFish server core.jar is not contained in the list of the installed bundles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, server, glassfish-4

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
gru 05, 2016 2:02:02 PM

```
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
gru 05, 2016 2:02:02 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
**WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.**
gru 05, 2016 2:02:02 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
**WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.**
gru 05, 2016 2:02:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles

**WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Servers/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.**
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@294d3883 in service registry.
```

I can't run my project.
What already I did:
- clear&build
- tryed to change ports from 8080 to 9090
- closed connections in TCPView on localports
- closed Java Binary process in task menager and still not working.

When i running project i got this:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Java Web Profile\MyProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
1047-1049 lines from build-impl.xml:

<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution/cause on another site, didn't resolve the issue for me but hopefully it can help you:

Reasons: In mac OS Sierra ,the new update blocks the sites which uses system proxy settings, where localhost,127.0.0.1 all connections are blocked.

Solution:
Step 1:  Go to system preference >Network>Select your wifi connection>Advanced>select proxies tab.
There check 3 options 1) Auto proxy Discovery 2)Automatic Proxy configuration 3) web proxy(http)

Step 2: Go to Netbeans>preferences>General> select use system proxy> reload> test connection
You may get connection successful.

If connection gets successful, Now Clean & build your Applications in netbeans and press run .
Hope it will work . In my case it works.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/30715103#message30715103
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268076